# Trying to learn to write a RegExp for PHP

Tags: php, regex, datetime

I am trying to learn how to write a RegEx but it seems all my searches lead to unclear information. So my question is two fold.

1. Does anyone have a good source on how a newbie could learn to write RegExs?
2. How could I write a RegEx that breaks the string 1y 311d 16h 42m into variables?

I'm looking to take the above text string and break it into something like:

```
$duration[years] = 1;
$duration[days] = 311;
$duration[hours] = 16;
$duration[minutes] = 42;
```

Please note the total digits might may not always be the same for example it could be two digit days. Something like. 25d or some could be omitted. I might just get days and hours. Lastly the order might change. Perhaps it is written days then years etc.

I know I could do this easily with an explode function and strpos, but I really want to learn Regex so I am using this as an example as I understand they can be very powerful for things like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Some useful pages:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info
- https://regex101.com/
- http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

2) Specifically, this:

```
$pattern = '/(?:(?P<years>\d+)y\s*)?(?:(?P<days>\d+)d\s*)?(?:(?P<hours>\d+)h\s*)?(?:(?P<minutes>\d+)m\s*)?/';
preg_match($pattern, '1y 311d 16h 42m', $duration);
print_r($duration);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1y 311d 16h 42m
//     [years] => 1
//     [1] => 1
//     [days] => 311
//     [2] => 311
//     [hours] => 16
//     [3] => 16
//     [minutes] => 42
//     [4] => 42
// )
preg_match($pattern, '311d 42m', $duration);
print_r($duration);
// Array
// (
//     [0] => 1y 311d 16h 42m
//     [years] =>
//     [1] =>
//     [days] => 311
//     [2] => 311
//     [hours] =>
//     [3] =>
//     [minutes] => 42
//     [4] => 42
// )
```

This will give fixed order though. If the order can change, regexp is not a good tool. It's still possible in this case, but rather awkward. Here it is:

```
$pattern = "/(?=.*?(?:(?P<years>\d+)y|$))(?=.*?(?:(?P<days>\d+)d|$))(?=.*?(?:(?P<hours>\d+)h|$))(?=.*?(?:(?P<minutes>\d+)m|$))/";    
preg_match($pattern, '311d 16h 1y', $duration);
print_r($duration);
// Array
// (
//     [0] =>
//     [years] => 1
//     [1] => 1
//     [days] => 311
//     [2] => 311
//     [hours] => 16
//     [3] => 16
// )
```

Entering these patterns (without the leading and trailing slashes) in regex101 will give you the explanation of what exactly it is trying to match. Find other examples from the [regex tag questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex) and enter them as well, and try to see how they work. Experience is the best teacher.

Comment: So you can put the array Key directly in the RegEx? What is making it add the extra key with the index number?

Comment: The named capture groups are an extension. Normally, capture groups are numeric; PHP's `(?P<name>...)` will create both a traditional numeric capture as well as the named one. The `0` group is different: it returns the whole matched substring; however, since in the last example everything is done by lookaheads which are null-width assertions, the matched substring is also width 0.